# Chrome extensions - reload matching tabs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-app

I want to know, is there a way from background page to reload all pages that matches the `content_scripts.matches` of the manifest.json ? Or do I have to define this somewhere else in my code, and loop through tabs to check if some match ?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: [chrome.runtime.getManifest()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest) + conversion of `matches` into regexps (`*` -> `.*?`) + manual comparison of each tab's url.

Comment: I guess no direct way? How about sending a signal from each tab (content script) and save the tabId in background, then refresh these tabs?

Comment: `getManifest` will do ! If you want to post as an answer, I will validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [chrome.runtime.getManifest()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest) to get all your content scripts declarations, manually convert the `matches` and other types of patterns into regexps and check all browser tabs urls.

This is a simplified version that doesn't account for excluded urls.

```js
var matches = [];

chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts.forEach(function(cs) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(matches, (cs.matches || []).map(matchToRegexp));
    Array.prototype.push.apply(matches, (cs.include_globs || []).map(globToRegexp));

    function matchToRegexp(match) {
        return match.replace(/[{}()\[\]\\.+?^$|]/g, "\\$&")
                    .replace(/\*/g, '.*?');
    }
    function globToRegexp(glob) {
        return glob.replace(/[{}()\[\]\\.+^$|]/g, "\\$&")
                   .replace(/\?/g, '.')
                   .replace(/\*/g, '.*?');
    }
});

var hasAllUrls = matches.indexOf('<all_urls>') >= 0 || matches.indexOf('*://*/*/') >= 0;
var rxMatches = hasAllUrls ? /^(https?|file|ftp):\/\/.+/
                           : new RegExp('^' + matches.join('$|^') + '$');

chrome.windows.getAll({
    populate: true,
    windowTypes: ['normal', 'panel', 'popup'],
}, function(windows) {
    windows.forEach(function(window) {
        window.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
            if (rxMatches.test(tab.url)) {
                chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Untested. In case of problems, debug it, fix it, edit this answer.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39095107/3959875) for a more proper glob-to-regexp conversion function.