# Javascript match URL with wildcards - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension which allows the user to modify content on specific websites. I'd like the user to be able to specify these websites using wildcards, for example `http://*.google.com` or `http://google.com/*`

I found the following code

```
currentUrl = "http://google.com/";
matchUrl = "http://*.google.com/*";
match = RegExp(matchUrl.replace(/\*/g, "[^]*")).test(currentUrl);
```

But there are a few problems with it.

`http://test.google.com/` is a match

`http://google.com/` is not a match

`http://test.google.com` is not a match

`http://.google.com/` is a match

> **Clarification:**
>
> `http://google.com` Isn't a match, and that is the real problem.

So how can I can I create a JavaScript code snippet that will check if there is a match correctly?

Comment: What's wrong with those results?

Comment: I think you should parse the URL first, then replace `*.` with `(?:[^/]*\.)?` in the base part and further `/*` with `(?:/[^]*)?`. Perhaps, a good idea is to escape special chars first.

Comment: The regex  should be [`/http:\/\/(?:[^\/]*\.)?google\.com(?:\/[^]*)?/`](https://regex101.com/r/jB2rK7/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest parsing the URL into protocol, base part and the rest, and then re-build the validation regex replacing `*` inside the base part with `(?:[^/]*\\.)*` and otherwise with `(?:/[^]*)?`. Also, you must escape all other special chars with `.replace(/[?()[\]\\.+^$|]/g, "\\$&")`. You will also need anchors (`^` for start of string and `$` for the end of string position) to match the *entire* string. A case insensitive `/i` modifier is just a bonus to make the pattern case insensitive.

So, for this exact `matchUrl`, the regex will look like

```
/^http:\/\/(?:[^\/]*\.)*google\.com(?:\/[^]*)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nR6lZ2/1)

```js
var rxUrlSplit = /((?:http|ftp)s?):\/\/([^\/]+)(\/.*)?/; 
var strs = ['http://test.google.com/', 'http://google.com/','http://test.google.com', 'http://.google.com/','http://one.more.test.google.com'];
var matchUrl = "http://*.google.com/*";
var prepUrl = "";
if ((m=matchUrl.match(rxUrlSplit)) !== null) {
 prepUrl = m[1]+"://"+m[2].replace(/[?()[\]\\.+^$|]/g, "\\$&").replace(/\*\\./g,'(?:[^/]*\\.)*').replace(/\*$/,'[^/]*');
  if (m[3]) { 
      prepUrl+= m[3].replace(/[?()[\]\\.+^$|]/g, "\\$&").replace(/\/\*(?=$|\/)/g, '(?:/[^]*)?');
   }
}
if (prepUrl) {
//  console.log(prepUrl); // ^http://(?:[^/]*\.)*google\.com(?:/[^]*)?$
  var rx = RegExp("^" + prepUrl + "$", "i");
  for (var s of strs) {
    if (s.match(rx)) {
     console.log(s + " matches!<br/>");
    } else {
     console.log(s + " does not match!<br/>");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that is precisely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -2):

with this matchUrl

```
matchUrl = "http://*.google.com/*";
```

the RexExp is something like this

```
"http://.*.google.com/.*"
```

so try to replace the ***** entered by the user with **.*** in the regexp match

you can use [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html) tool to test it

Comment: You have not tried that on all the input strings. The `.` *requires* a char after the optional `.*`.

Comment: @Wiktor I don't understand what I missed.

Comment: @Script_Coded The question was not clear... You have to specify well what have to match and what not... If you want match also http://google.com the RegEx is "http://.*[.]*google.com[/]*.*"
Nice to hear that you solved that, but you have to be more clear next time IMHO.

Comment: @Alberto I do realize that the question wasn't to clear, but having only a couple of minutes between lessons I did my best, why I also added a correction. The question is answered, however, and there is no need for further discussion.